# Ограничения в телеграмм боте для inline клавиатуры C#

Tags: c#, telegram

Снова здравствуйте, я продолжаю писать бота для телеграмм на C#. Я хочу попросить вас, что бы вы помогли со следующие проблемой, какие ограничения можно повесить на inline клавиатуру, чтобы не происходило спама командами?

Comment: timer https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Anton Nikolaev данный подход не работает)

Comment: Ответ я опубликовал здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1223443/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%91%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-c/1225062#1225062