# Как приостановить приём команд в боте? C#

Tags: c#, telegram

Я опять со своим телеграмм ботом) Как приостановить приём команд в боте? C#

В общем я пишу простенькую игру "Орёл или Решка". Когда перед игроком стоит выбор перед ним появляется клавиатура. Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы если нажал "Орёл", а потом резко "Решка" до исчезновения клавиатуры, то и должен засчитаться "Орёл", вторая команда "Решка" читаться не должна.

[image: Клавиатура]

Обработка команд

```
  private static async void BotOnMessageReceived(object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        await botClient.SetWebhookAsync("");

        var message = e.Message;
        int chatId = message.From.Id;
        DateTime date = message.Date;

        var replyKeyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(KeyboardsComands.StartKeyboard(), true, false);
        Console.WriteLine($"{KeyboardsComands.GetTelegramID(message)} отправил сообщение: {message.Text}");

        if (KeyboardsComands.CheckText(message))
        {
            switch (message.Text)
            {
                case "/start":
                    CasinoBotDatabase.AddUsers(message.From.Id, $"{message.From.FirstName} {message.From.LastName}", 25);
                    await CommandsHandler.Start(botClient, chatId, replyKeyboard, KeyboardsComands.GetTelegramID(message));
                    break;
                case " Подбросить монетку!":
                    await CommandsHandler.FlipCoin(botClient, chatId);
                    break;
                case " Помощь":
                    await CommandsHandler.Help(botClient, chatId);
                    break;
                case " Баланс":
                    await CommandsHandler.ReturnBalace(botClient, chatId);
                    break;
                case " Орёл":
                    await CommandsHandler.ResultGame(botClient, chatId, "Орёл", replyKeyboard, date);
                    break;
                case " Решка":
                    await CommandsHandler.ResultGame(botClient, chatId, "Решка", replyKeyboard, date);
                    break;
                case " Играть ещё!":
                    await CommandsHandler.UpdateGame(botClient, chatId, replyKeyboard, KeyboardsComands.GetTelegramID(message));
                    break;
                case " Назад":
                    await CommandsHandler.Back(botClient, chatId, replyKeyboard, KeyboardsComands.GetTelegramID(message));
                    break;
                default:
                    await botClient.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, $"{Char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F97A)}" + KeyboardsComands.DefaultText + $"\n\n{char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F48E)} Выберите одну из следующих команд:", replyMarkup: replyKeyboard);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Сам обработчик команд

```
 public static class CommandsHandler
{
    
    public static async Task Start(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId, ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboard, string playerID)
    {
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, ReturnStartText(playerID, GetBalance(chatId), GetGeneralDeposit(chatId)), ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: replyKeyboard);
    }

    public static async Task FlipCoin(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId)
    {
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, $"{char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F4D7)} <b>Победа: x2\n{char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F4D5)} Проигрыш: x0</b>\n\n{char.ConvertFromUtf32(0x1F4B0)} Выберите сумму ставки:", ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: BetKeyboard());
    }

    public static async Task Help(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId)
    {
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, KeyboardsComands.Help);
    }

    public static async Task ReturnBalace(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId)
    {
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, $"Ваш баланс: <b>{GetBalance(chatId)} руб</b>", ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: BalanceButton());
    }

    public static async Task ResultGame(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId, string choice, ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboard, DateTime date)
    {
        Balance = GetBalance(chatId);
        AddCommands(chatId, date);
        if (choice == "Орёл")
        {
            string result = PlayGame(choice, Bet);
            replyKeyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(PlayMore(), true, false);
            UpdateBalance(chatId, Balance);
            await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, result, ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: replyKeyboard);
        }

        else
        {
            string result = PlayGame(choice, Bet);
            replyKeyboard = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup(PlayMore(), true, false);
            UpdateBalance(chatId, Balance);
            await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, result, ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: replyKeyboard);
        }
    }
    
    public static async Task UpdateGame(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId, ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboard, string playerID)
    {
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, ReturnStartText(playerID, GetBalance(chatId), GetGeneralDeposit(chatId)), ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: replyKeyboard);
    }

    public static async Task Back(TelegramBotClient bot, int chatId, ReplyKeyboardMarkup replyKeyboard, string playerID)
    {
        await bot.SendTextMessageAsync(chatId, ReturnStartText(playerID, GetBalance(chatId), GetGeneralDeposit(chatId)), ParseMode.Html, replyMarkup: replyKeyboard);
    }
}
```

Comment: Оборвать аутентификацию?  Выключить бота? Не заплатить за интернет? Выдернуть шнур?

Comment: @Andrew, хороший способ, но не подойдёт) Может ты знаешь, как сделать так, чтобы не происходило флуда командами от пользователя?

Comment: записывай время последней команды от конкретного пользователя в базу данных. Если теперешнее время меньше промежутка в условных 10 секунд - выйди из метода

Comment: В вопросе не хватает существенных подробностей: как принимаются команды для бота, как обрабатываются.

Comment: @AK я отредактировал, посмотрите пожалуйста, уже 3 день мучаюсь, сейчас остановился на способе с базой данных, однако не особо получается.

Comment: Если вы не работали с базой данных, то действительно это непросто -- сразу браться за такие сложные задачи. Возможно, вам стоит потренироваться сначала отдельно? Просто есть и другие варианты, например Throttling - но они тоже явно выше вашего текущего уровня. В этом случае: отложить реальный проект в сторону, попробовать упрощённые примеры, потренироваться, а потом уже вернуться. У вас же мечты о серебрянной пуле, которых увы нет. Либо идите на биржу фриланса, где вам сделают под ключ, либо учитесь сами, доходите до того уровня, чтобы сделать самостоятельно. Пока gap слишком большой для вас.

Comment: @AK я попытаюсь разобраться, у меня даже кое как получилось сделать через БД правда криво, накидайте пожалуйста вариантов решения данной задачи)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данную проблему я решил следующим способом.

Имейте словарь<int, DateTime>, хранящий идентификатор пользователя и время последней команды. Когда пользователь отправляет команду / нажимает кнопку, если последний раз это было менее 5 секунд назад, игнорируйте ее.

```
    private static bool NotFlood(int user_id, DateTime timeCommand)
    {
        timeCommand = DateTime.UtcNow;
        DateTime LastTimeCommand = DateTime.UtcNow;
        if (UserCommands.ContainsKey(user_id))
        {
            LastTimeCommand = UserCommands[user_id];
            UserCommands[user_id] = timeCommand;
            if (timeCommand < LastTimeCommand.AddSeconds(5))
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            UserCommands.Add(user_id, timeCommand);
            return true;
        }
    }
```